# How to write ResponseEntity to HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring

How to write ResponseEntity to HttpServletResponse (as it makes @ResponseBody)?

For example I have authentication success handler:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Map responseMap = new HashMap();
    responseMap.put("user", "my_user_name");
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter I have error: "Could not write content: not in non blocking mode."

Code:

```
HttpOutputMessage outputMessage = new ServletServerHttpResponse(response);
messageConverter.write(responseEntity, null, outputMessage);
```

What are the best practices of implementation handlers with HttpServletResponse?

Comment: You don't have to write the ResponseEntity on the response, but its encapsulated object. Exactly how it's done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43845840/379173

Answer (score 16):

You can use a custom response object, convert it to a JSON string using the Jackson's [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and write the result into the request.

---

## Example

**MyResponseObject.java**

```
private String user;

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

**MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java**

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    MyResponseObject responseObj = new MyResponseObject();
    responseObj.setUser("my_user_name");

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseObj);

    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(json);
    httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on [andrearro88's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43845840/679240), I have made this generic function to copy a `ResponseEntity` to a `HttpServletResponse`:

```
public static void populateResponse(ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity, HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
        throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : responseEntity.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
        String chave = header.getKey();
        for (String valor : header.getValue()) {
            servletResponse.addHeader(chave, valor);                
        }
    }

    servletResponse.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
    servletResponse.getWriter().write(responseEntity.getBody());
}
```

Comment: Beware: `responseEntity.getBody()` can be `null`! Check first, then write if it's not `null`.

Comment: The problem with this function is that it uses only `String` for response body, while in @andrearro88's answer we can see usage of object mapper to write the json, meaning that this doesnt work if the generic value of ResponseEntity is anything other than String

Comment: Yes, I added this response mostly because it copies the headers, which some people (including me) may certainly need. Just combine or adapt the two, depending on what your need.