# Send Restful API JSON response from Spring Boot Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest

I am using following filter for checking if a specific HTTP Header is present on api request.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HeaderValidationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
String headerValue = request.getHeader("RANDOM_HEADER");

if(Objects.isNull(headerValue)) {
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseToSend = ResponseGen.create("FAILED", "Missing Authentication Header", new Object())));

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.getOutputStream().write(responseToSend);
    return;
}

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

It returns response as JSON but with added object keys like `headers`,`statusCode`etc and the payload I provided is placed inside `body`. As I have a standard error response defined on the Project, I cannot return the response at it is. (See the following response)

```
{
"headers": {},
"body": {
    "status": "FAILURE",
    "message": "Missing Authentication Header",
    "data": {}
},
"statusCode": "UNAUTHORIZED",
"statusCodeValue": 401
}
```

I want the response to be only in this format:

```
{
    "status": "FAILED",
    "message": "Missing Authentication Header",
    "data": {}
}
```

I have tried returning using generic exception handler with `@ControllerAdvice` but it doesn't capture exception from `Filters` as it is executed before `DispatcherServlet`

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you share the code how do you override the response? I guess you are overriding the default behavior of the response.

Comment: @PetrJordán Couldn't understand what exactly you meant when you say override? I haven't overridden any response, just generated ResponseEntity and sent it

Comment: I mean it like it is not standard behavior of the spring-boot. I thought you override the default response format. Can you try to write own response - something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162392/how-to-write-responseentity-to-httpservletresponse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you see

```json
{
"headers": {...},
"body": {...},
"statusCode": ...,
"statusCodeValue": ...
}
```

is the serialized `ResponseEntity` that you write as a response in your filter:

```java
ResponseEntity<Object> responseToSend = ResponseGen.create("FAILED", "Missing Authentication Header", new Object())));
```

Obviously, if you need a response in another format you'll have to use an object that is serialized to the desired format as a response. E.g.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class StandardError {
    private String status;
    private String message;
    private Object data;
}

....

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                HttpServletResponse response, 
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    if (Objects.isNull(headerValue)) {
        StandardError responseToSend = new StandardError("FAILED", "Missing Authentication Header", new Object());

        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getOutputStream().write(responseToSend);
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Why didn't i think of this? Tried bunch of work around, and got frustrated. Thank you @dekkard .